# How to Pass using angularjs array list to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

> $scope.AddRecord = [];
>
> var item = { 'budget_item_id': $scope.item_id, 'budget_item_discription': $scope.item_discription, 'budget_item_quantity': $scope.item_quantity, 'budget_item_unit': $scope.item_unit, 'budget_item_rate': $scope.item_rate, 'budget_item_discount': $scope.item_discount };
>
> $scope.AddRecord.push(item);

I am able to store more than 20 records, How do I pass all records to the server?

If I store more than 30 records in an AngularJS array, How should I pass the array to my server?

Comment: Could you please show what is your server side object?

Comment: Does the size of array list matter unless you specifically restrict the body-upload size ?

Comment: Why did you specify Razor as the tags for this question? How do you try to communicate with your server? Via Web API?

Comment: public string AddBudgetItem(BudgetItem[] focl)
        {

            
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using `$http`.

```
$http({
    url: ServerAddress+"/login", method: 'POST',
    data: item,
    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
})
```

Seeing the values you want to send, there will not be any issue in sending 30 key-values (it's very small amount of data in fact).

On server side the request handler function can access the sent data as key value pair (code specific details depends on server side implementation)

Comment: I am not understand x-www-form

Comment: header attribute in not required for $http() unless you want to send large data in query string.
you can check only with "url" and "data" attributes of $http service.